# Getting Content from URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am performing sentiment analysis on a URL. For getting content from URL, I write this code:

```
import numpy as np
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = target_url

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content,'html.parser')

content=soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'td-post-content'})
content=content[0].text.replace('\n'," ")
```

but this keep saying that my list is out of index.

I tried to change list to dictionary but it still giving me error of out of index.
What do I have to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Probbly `content[0]` has no item and then give that error check `print(len(content))` has item inside. Check the `soup.Findall()` working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
url = target_url

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all(class_="td-post-content")
content = content[0].text.replace('\n', " ")
```

If the above code doesn't work, share the URL of the target page, to provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: [link](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/readersblog/shreyansh-mangla/impact-of-covid-19-on-indian-economy-2-35042/)